# jquery autocomplete принудительный вызов

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Есть элемент на странице на котором Autocomplete

```
<input onclick="$(this).val(""); $(this).autocomplete().focus();" class="filters ac_input" style="width: 40px;" id="filter_num" value="- № -" ref="num" autocomplete="off">
```

вот настройки

```
 $(this).autocomplete('/?action=gkAs2Suggestions&method=filter&stringType='+$(this).attr('ref'),
            {
                width: wi, selectFirst: false, autoFill: false, multiple: false, mustMatch: false,
                max: 500, minChars: 0, delay: 100
            });
```

Каким образом можно вызвать autocomplete событием ? В частности событием on("input")?

Что бы появилась подсказка со значениями, то есть отработал autocomplete.

Смысл в том что все работает, при левом клике по input`у, при вводе значения с клавиатуры, при вставке значения с помощью ctrl+v. 
Но при вставки мышкой (пр.клик-> вставить) не работает =(

Answer (score 0):

Пробовали настроить реакцию на событие input и навесить на тег?

```
$('div').on('input','input.ac_input',function(){
 $(this).autocomplete...
})
```